# PF not forwarding incoming traffic on loopback from one port to another

Tags: network, firewall, proxy, pfctl

*Scenario*

I have a server listening on port `3000` on `localhost`. I want incoming traffic to `localhost:8080` to be forwarded to that server.

My set up:

1. Server listens on port `3000`; nothing listens on port `8080`
2. pfctl: `rdr pass log on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port 8080 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3000`
3. watch all incoming connections to port `8080` on `lo0` interface: `sudo tcpdump -nn -i lo0 dst port 8080 -v`

*Test*

`curl localhost:8080`

*Expected*

1. server on port `3000` gets request from curl
2. tcpdump returns smth like: 127.0.0.1.57330 > 127.0.0.1.**3000** < more-info >

*Reality*

1. curl gets `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost
   port 8080: Connection refuse`
2. tcpdump returns 127.0.0.1.57330 > 127.0.0.1.**8080** < more-info >

=> tcpdump output means that the rule was not applied since the destination port is still **8080** and not **3000**.

*Question*

Where did my configuration went wrong and how to make it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it's not `pfctl` (who forwards), but rather PF instead. `pfctl` is just a controlling utility (hence "ctl").

Now to debugging. You gave none of that info so that all is based on my own expertise and assumptions, read "guesses".

`pfctl -si` should show you if PF is actually enabled. Yes, rules can be loaded into it, but being disabled it won't process traffic.

`pfctl -vsn` should show if your NAT rules are getting any hits or they aren't.

And if you have some other PF rules applied you'd better be sure there's no `set skip on lo0`.

Comment: 1. `pfctl -si` shows enabled. 2. pfctl -vsn doesn't show my config at all. I know my config is loaded because I used `pfctl -vef <file>` and saw that my rule was loaded.

Comment: "`pfctl -vsn` doesn't show my config at all" — that's what you call "reality vs. expectations". Simplify your config and try again.

Comment: my problem was as you said, the configuration was not loaded. I don't know why. When I run `pfctl -vef <file>` I saw a line `Loading anchor ... rdr pass log on lo0...`, which is my rule.